# How do I add an URL parameter to an URL given a data attribute in the href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with this:

Html

```
<a href="#2" class="page-link" data-wpurl="?p=2" onmousedown="rwt(this)">2</a>
```

JS

```
rwt = function(e){
    $(".t-pageholder").load("http://mysite.asd/index.php/".data('wpurl'));
};
```

How can i go link `http://mysite.asd/index.php?p=2` with this code?

Comment: Please state your question properly,What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Don't sidestep the warning about using words like 'problem' in the question title. Be a little more specific. We know its a problem, otherwise you wouldn't be here.

Comment: use `$(e).data('wpurl')` to retrieve the value, and also use `+` for string concat

Comment: Why are you adding the JavaScript inline and not just via an event handler like `$('.page-link').on('mousedown', function() { ... })`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following : 
Html

```
<a href="#2" class="page-link" data-wpurl="?p=2" onmousedown="rwt(this)">2</a>
```

Javascript

```
rwt = function(e){
    var wpurl = $(e).data('wpurl');
    $(".t-pageholder").load("http://mysite.asd/index.php/"+wpurl);
};
```

Comment: it work only if you have only one link with the class `page-link`, use `$(e)` to get the one clicked.